# SQL Server : BULK INSERT FAILED IID_IColumnsInfo

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulk

I use a BULK insert in a procStock, and got this Error Message:

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 8, Line 2
>   The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
>
> Msg 7301, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
>   Cannot obtain the required interface ("IID_IColumnsInfo") from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

I look for post in Stack and find some solution advice to use ROWTERMINATOR='0x0a', but I still got the same error.

```
    SET @sir_de_executat = '
    BULK INSERT #test
    FROM ''d:\scripts\test.csv''
    WITH (
        FIRSTROW=2
        , FORMATFILE=''d:\scripts\aaa2.fmt''
        , FIELDTERMINATOR = '';''
        , ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a''
    )'
```

Thanks for your help.

Here is a csv sample

```
BPARTNER;ME_TITLE_0208;BP_LSTNAME_0209;BP_FSTNAME_0210;STR_SUPPL1_0211;STR_SUPPL2_0212;HOUSE_NUM1_0213;HOUSE_NUM2_0214;STREET60_0215;STR_SUPPL4_0216;POSTALCODE_0217;CITY_1_0218;TEL_NUMBER_0219;FAX_NUMBER_0220;ZCHASSNR;ZFAHRZEUG__ZBRAND;ZFAHRZEUG__ZMODELKEY;ZFAHRZEUG__ZFISCHP;ZFAHRZEUG__ZMOTRVAR;ZFAHRZEUG__ZZULASSG;ZCREGDAT;/BIC/ZDDEALER;/BIC/Z_REGRNO_0124;ZFAHRZEUG__ZMOTR_KB4;ZFAHRZEUG__ZMODJAHR
6016562635;0002;FOO;BAR;;;823;;RUE DE LA SOUTE;;60400;CUTS;;;AZEZZZ8U0HR067422;AU;8UGBGY;0008;D;20170803;20170803;FRAA01612;EP-803-RP;DFTA;2017
```

Here is the fmt format file

```
10.0
25
1       SQLCHAR             0       20      "\t"      1     bpartner                                               SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
2       SQLCHAR             0       30      "\t"      2     title                                                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
3       SQLCHAR             0       256     "\t"      3     last_name                                              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             0       256     "\t"      4     first_name                                             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
5       SQLCHAR             0       256     "\t"      5     street2                                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
6       SQLCHAR             0       256     "\t"      6     street3                                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
7       SQLCHAR             0       60      "\t"      7     house_number                                           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
8       SQLCHAR             0       60      "\t"      8     house_number_completion                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
9       SQLCHAR             0       256     "\t"      9     street                                                 SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
10      SQLCHAR             0       256     "\t"      10    street5                                                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
11      SQLCHAR             0       30      "\t"      11    postal_code                                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
12      SQLCHAR             0       256     "\t"      12    city                                                   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
13      SQLCHAR             0       128     "\t"      13    tel_number                                             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
14      SQLCHAR             0       128     "\t"      14    fax_number                                             SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
15      SQLCHAR             0       50      "\t"      15    chassis_number                                         SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
16      SQLCHAR             0       10      "\t"      16    brand                                                  SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
17      SQLCHAR             0       15      "\t"      17    model_key                                              SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
18      SQLCHAR             0       15      "\t"      18    fiscal_horse_power                                     SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
19      SQLCHAR             0       60      "\t"      19    engine_option                                          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
20      SQLCHAR             0       24      "\t"      20    first_registration_date                                ""
21      SQLCHAR             0       24      "\t"      21    current_registration_date                              ""
22      SQLCHAR             0       100     "\t"      22    sales_dealer                                           SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
23      SQLCHAR             0       100     "\t"      23    licence_plate                                          SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
24      SQLCHAR             0       60      "\t"      24    engine_code                                            SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
25      SQLCHAR             0       12      "\r\n"    25    year                                                   ""
```

Comment: Could you add sample lines from your source file?

Comment: Why did you use `0x0a`  that terminator instead of the default, `\n`? Did you encounter a *different* error and thought that the terminator is wrong? Or that SQL Server doesn't recognize special characters? (it does(. Even if it was, `0x0a` is just a sequence of 4 characters, not the `\n` character

Comment: Try to write a correct BULK INSERT statement first. *Then* try to find a way to convert it into a string. BTW, *why* use a string at all? Why not call BULK INSERT directly, passing any values that need changing as parameters?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos same error with the `\n`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This code used to work for a long time, and a day it stop working. But I just want to find a little patch to correct this

Comment: Could you please provide the structure of your destination table?

Comment: @fxlacroix The format file overrides the command line settings. The reason this worked is that the format file overrides the invalid *row* separator with that `\r\n` at the end. The field separator is `\t`. It doesn't work now because you tried to load a file with *different* separators without actually modifying the field, row separators

Comment: If you want to load a different format, either use the command line and no format file, or use a different format file that specifies the separators you want.

Comment: thank you @PanagiotisKanavos I m gonna make it a try !

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos  it works with the modification of "\t" to ";". I didn't know the file format override the direct parameters. Thank you again,

Answer (score 0):

When you'are creating your fmt file, you have to specify the Field Terminator to be same as used in your CSV file.
Documentation is given for [`bcp` command](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485(v=sql.110).aspx#CodeSnippetContainerCode_0a684195-d4f4-431e-9c77-b83c5beb8db9)  , you have to specify the `-t` option

```
bcp AdventureWorks..myDepartment in C:\myDepartment-c-t.txt -c -t ; -r \n -T
```

As explained  in [this documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191485(v=sql.110).aspx#Anchor_0) , the default field terminator is the `\t`, it seems to be the problem.

Comment: The bcp link is invalid. Specifying `\r\n` as row terminator is done by `-r \r` (see [Specify Field and Row Terminators (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-field-and-row-terminators-sql-server) - Characters Supported As Terminators).

Comment: Thx for the correction, I have fixed the link, and I have fixed the option `-r \n` because you are right, the Row Terminator is automatically prefixed with a `\r`